# When passing a function as a pointer, how do I specify the parameters?

Tags: c++

I've found a ton of info on function pointers, but one thing is really confusing. How am I supposed to specify the parameters of the function that's being passed? An example from what I've been trying to do...

```
void BatchDelete(string head, string filename, void (*f)(string, string));
void DeleteOneNode(string head, string song);
BatchDelete(head, filename, DeleteOneNode)
```

From what I've read and seen, when passing a function, it should never have parenthesis because that's a function call, but how do I specify what two strings DeleteOneNode get?

Comment: I'd pass them in `void BatchDelete(string head, string filename, void (*f)(string, string), string param1, string param2);`. That or make a wrapper class.

Comment: " how do I specify what two strings DeleteOneNode get?" - somewhere inside `BatchDelete` you will call `DeleteOneNode("a string", "another string");` . You can prepare those strings in any way

Comment: I think I see now! So, I'd pass the two strings in as separate parameters, alongside the function, then call the the function passed with those two strings.

Comment: Another option is make the function you call accept a `std::function<void()>` instead - why should it ask for a function taking parameters it doesn't know how to provide? - then the caller passes say a lambda ala `[]() { myfunc(str1, str2); }`.

Comment: IMHO, passing a function pointer along with its parameters is not the typical usecase for function pointers. I mean if the caller of your `BatchDelete` function already knows the function to be called and the parameters, there is no need to pass this around but it could simply call the function by it self. However, it is hard to say without knowing more of your code and in you particular case it might make sense to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. A function pointer is a pointer to a function to be called, it is up to the call site to supply parameters.

```
#include <iostream>

void target(const std::string& str)
{
    std::cout << "fn " << str << "\n";
}

void caller(void (*fn)(const std::string&))
{
    fn("hello world");
}

int main()
{
    caller(target);
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/AWsxk5

In the samples you gave, `BatchDelete` takes some parameters from which it appears to find songs, then it calls your callback function with the parameters needed, passes them for you - you don't need to worry about trying to pass them.

That's the point of the function pointer there, it finds the files to delete but then it wants you to provide the function do to the deleting, and more to the point, the purpose of a function pointer is a contract about *receipt* of the arguments from the intermediate function.

--- Edit ---

A more "batchdelete" like version of the example:

```
#include <iostream>

void callbackfn(std::string path, std::string filename)
{
    std::cout << "delete " << path << "\\" << filename << "\n";
}

void BatchDelete(std::string path, std::string file, void (*fn)(std::string, std::string))
{
    // pretend these are songs we found in playlist.mpl
    fn(path, "Alanis\\*.*");
    fn(path, "Mix Tape\\ReallySadSong.mp3");
}

int main()
{
    BatchDelete("C:\\Music\\", "playlist.mpl", callbackfn);
}
```

http://ideone.com/NEpXeC

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense. I think this will work out just fine.